# Stop verbose in ansible.playbook.PlayBook

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible in my CLi. So all error-handling I want to do by myself and I don't want to give extra information that might disoriented  an user.

When I tried to run ansible playbook in python code and I've receive verbose msg's:

```
PLAY [Role] ***************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [base-devel-go | Install go lang support] *******************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]
```

I use [ansible-playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/fbc525cfb66563eedc2755e363c28206a5dc6e7d/bin/ansible-playbook) as source for my flow. Now I see a lot of verbose stuff. I want hide it but I couldn't find how to do this?:

```
playbook = params["playbook"]
inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(hosts)
inventory.set_playbook_basedir(os.path.dirname(playbook))

stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()
playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(
    stats, verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)


params["inventory"] = inventory
params["stats"] = stats
params["callbacks"] = playbook_cb
params["runner_callbacks"] = runner_cb

pb = ansible.playbook.PlayBook(**playbook_params)
pr = pb.run()
```

I tried to find in [callbacks.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/fbc525cfb66563eedc2755e363c28206a5dc6e7d/lib/ansible/callbacks.py) but my level of python is less to find answer

Comment: If you don't care for the output then do `ansible-playbook pb.yml > /dev/null 2>&1`. What you see is NOT verbose. If you wanna see real verbose use `-vvvv` option.

Comment: It's what I see when run in python!

Comment: again: "What you see is NOT verbose".. it's the "minimal" output that ansible prints.. redirect it to `/dev/null` !

Comment: I understand this. But I don't run ansible-playbook. I did cli that use python bindings and when I run this part -> user see this output. Here is problem (I think) https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/fbc525cfb66563eedc2755e363c28206a5dc6e7d/lib/ansible/callbacks.py#L471

Comment: One of the most valid questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simplest way to disable output.
I am using ansible in CLi. So when I run it thought python bindings -> there are output. But I found way to disable it:

```
from ansible import callbacks
# pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
def display(msg, color=None, stderr=False,
            screen_only=False, log_only=True, runner=None):
    # prevent a very rare case of interlaced multiprocess I/O
    callbacks.log_flock(runner)
    msg2 = msg
    if color:
        msg2 = stringc(msg, color)
    if not log_only:
        if not stderr:
            try:
                print msg2
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print msg2.encode('utf-8')
        else:
            try:
                print >>sys.stderr, msg2
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print >>sys.stderr, msg2.encode('utf-8')
    if callbacks.constants.DEFAULT_LOG_PATH != '':
        while msg.startswith("\n"):
            msg = msg.replace("\n", "")
        if not screen_only:
            if color == 'red':
                logging.error(msg)
            else:
                logging.info(msg)
    callbacks.log_unflock(runner)

# disable verbose
callbacks.display = display
```